# Copy and paste in Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I try to copy and paste from file to another in Excel with  this code:

```
from win32com import client

xlapp = client.Dispatch("excel.application")
work = xlapp.Workbooks
copysheet = work.Open("D:/mm/trn files/Field Inspection Test Notification for 
ERC Review (CI).xlsx" )
cs = copysheet.Worksheets(1)
cs.Visible = 1
cs.Range("B2:G66").Copy()
pastesheet = work.Open("D:/mm/trn files/Field Inspection Test Notification 
for ERC Review (ss).xlsx")
pastesheet.Paste(cs.Range("B2:G66"))
```

But it gives me this error:

```
raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library._Workbook instance at 0x47919440>' object has no attribute 'Paste'
```

And I don't know what's the problem. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Hi Doaa Sobhy - I am not familiar with the win32com client, but from your code it looks like pastesheet is a workbook object, which means that it will not have a 'paste' method.  Isn't it the case that you need to identify/select the sheet within the Field Inspection Test Notification workbook first?  E.g. pastebook = work.Open(...),  pastesheet = pastebook.Worksheets(...) etc, until you get to a range object that should have a paste method?  Not sure though!

Answer (score 0):

The pastesheet is a Workbook object, which does not have a Paste method. You might do something similar to what you did with the copysheet object. 
i.e.

```
ps = pastesheet.Worksheets(1)
ps.Paste(cs.Range("B2:G66"))
```